# MVC5 Sanitizing CKEditor Input

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, ckeditor

I've been trying to figure out how to protect my website against XSS while using CKEditor.  By Default MVC5 will validate all the input for tags, but I have [AllowHtml] Attribute on my Comments field.

```
public class Post
{
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Comment {get; set;}
}
```

Now on my View I need to print it out as

```
@Html.Raw(@Model.Comment)
```

I can easily go and insert a `<script>alert('hello');</script>` and it will produce the alert.  I am trying to figure out how to protect myself from it.  I thought about using the [AntiXSS](http://wpl.codeplex.com/) library, but the download page said it reached its end of life.

The website also states:
"In ASP.NET v5 a white list based encoder will be the only encoder."

So at this point I'm quite confused on how to deal with XSS in MVC5 for text areas where I need to allow HTML tags to come through.

To clarify my questions:

1. How do I sanitize and store the value in the database
2. How do I display the value in the View

I have gone through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735214/allowing-only-certain-html-tags-as-user-input), however, I am confused if the first example on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581936/how-to-sanitize-input-from-mce-in-asp-net) is a good way to do it. The post doesn't seem to have gotten a lot of attention so I'm wary to blindly trusting it.

Additionaly, I do not understand if I am suppose to use `@Html.Raw(@Model.Comment)` to output it, or another way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allowing only certain HTML tags as user input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735214/allowing-only-certain-html-tags-as-user-input)