# How to extend Html.Raw in order to Sanitize dangerous HTML data before displaying

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xss, html-helper, razorengine

I inherited a web-app which already has some input fields accepting plain Html from user. *(you may understand that the XSS (Cross Site Scripting) bell rings here...! )*

The same input is displayed on specific view pages with the use of @Html.Raw *(... the bell now rings louder)*

And, to be able to do that work, the [ValidateInput(false)] decorator on the Controller and  [AllowHtml] on the Model field, comes to fill the picture... *(what can i say about the bell!!!)*

Now, *before someone convicts some programmer to death* :-) let me make clear that this dangerous input functionality is allowed to users of specific-admin-role. So this is kind of controlled situation.

Lately, though, we decided to **add some control** to this situation, as this functionality creates risk from inside, in case of malicious behavior of the admin user himself.

**The easy implementable option** would be to disable this whole funcionality and add some Markdown editor instead, which will store harmless Rich-Text-Format input, BUT still I would have to transform all the **existing data** to this Markdown, so that they display correctly.

**What I need, though,** is to be able to lower the risk of inside - **not eliminate** - by adding some sort of Filter of Script tags and other dangerous tags, as an extension of the existing Html.Raw helper.

Can anyone suggest a way to extend or wrap the existing HtmlHelper, please?

Here is the Metadata info:

```
// Summary:
//     Returns markup that is not HTML encoded.
//
// Parameters:
//   value:
//     The HTML markup.
//
// Returns:
//     The HTML markup without encoding.
public IHtmlString Raw(string value);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Microsoft AntiXSS library you can avoid Cross Site Scripting attacks.Install `AntiXSS 4.3.0`. from nuget `Install-Package AntiXSS`.

```
@Html.Raw(Microsoft.Security.Application.Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(value))
```

if this didnt work then try with AjaxControlToolkit's `HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider` .using this you can whitelist some tags and attributes.

you can check this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581936/how-to-sanitize-input-from-mce-in-asp-net)

Comment: This seems perfect, thank you Pavan! I am now testing the result.. One quick question on this: Could I use something like this for INPUT sanitization as well?

Comment: @cnom yes,you can use

Comment: after a bit more thorough investigation, I found out that this library kills much existing formatting (i.e. font colors, background colors etc), which seems a bit weird... Tht is why I have not yet marked your answer, I m still in search of a better solution!

Comment: did you check `AjaxControlToolkit's HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider`

Comment: I found it in http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ but it has no documentation. It seems to work out-of-the-box on the AjaxControlToolkit embedded HTMLEditorExtender, BUT, I use a different editor: TinyMCE. Could you help me? Is there a Method of this library, I can use with 3rd party component like mine?

Comment: This does not answer the question. He asked for a way to extend Html.Raw. This answer requires him to replace all uses of it which may not be an option for some.